# How to get The current Item Position of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get The current Item position Of FirebaseRecyclerAdpter

`madapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<user, contact.UserViewHolder>(user.class, R.layout.activity_dialogs_list, contact.UserViewHolder.class, muserref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final UserViewHolder viewHolder, user model, final int position) {
                final String ais = model.getName();
                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                final String b = model.getQuery();`

(final UserViewHolder viewHolder, user model, ---->final int position<------)
how to use that int position to find the current position.

Comment: Can you give some details about this question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to change the position of the item,using on notifiyonitemmoved() method

Comment: That sounds like you should not do it in your adapter! @ibm.shaikh
Your question is highly unclear, please add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your concrete problem, but I suggest You t use

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

It is more flexible if you extend this class, and create your own adapter.
In this case you will have a dataset, which can be easily modified.

Also, the accessing of data is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that position in the populateViewHolder is the current position of the view.

Easiest way is to create an integer value `position` in the ViewHolder class and assign the value to it like this

```
madapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<user, contact.UserViewHolder>(user.class, R.layout.activity_dialogs_list, contact.UserViewHolder.class, muserref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final UserViewHolder viewHolder, user model, final int position) {
                final String ais = model.getName();
                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setPosition(position);
                final String b = model.getQuery();
```

And you can use the position by `viewHolder.getPosition();`

Comment: After my opinion, the viewHolder should not contain the position. The viewHolder should contain information about the displaying of item, it should not conatin any data related to position.

Comment: Is there any design guidelines regarding that?

For example, if you need to display the current position in the view itself, you should have the position index, right?

Comment: If you read about recyclerview adapter, you'll see. The model of item, and the  view are decoupled.